# StAX - writeCharacters(), how to not escape Chinese,Japanese characters?

Tags: java

XMLStreamWriter#writeCharacters(...)

The writeCharacters(...) method is used to escape characters such as &, <, >, and ". 
(from   http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E17802_01/webservices/webservices/docs/2.0/tutorial/doc/StAX4.html)

but when I write some Chinese, Japanese characters, and the output XML
file is not encoded in "UTF-8", but is "GBK" or "Shift-JIS". The Chinese, Japanese characters is also escaped, just like

"汉语, English, にほんご"  --->  "&#x6c49;&#x8bed;, English, &#x306b;&#x307b;&#x3093;&#x3054;"

Is there anyway to resolve it?

---

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {  
    // GBK  
    System.out.println("JVM default charset = " + Charset.defaultCharset());  

    String s = "汉语, English, にほんご";  

    XMLOutputFactory output = XMLOutputFactory.newInstance();  
    output.setProperty(XMLOutputFactory.IS_REPAIRING_NAMESPACES, false);  

    OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream("C:/aa.txt");  
    XMLStreamWriter writer = output.createXMLStreamWriter(out, "UTF-8");  
    // When output encoding is "UTF-8", result is something like:  
    // <?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?><a>汉语, English, にほんご</a>  

    // When output encoding is "GBK", result is something like:  
    // <?xml version='1.0' encoding='GBK'?><a>&#x6c49;&#x8bed;, English, &#x306b;&#x307b;&#x3093;&#x3054;</a>  

    writer.writeStartDocument();  
    writer.setDefaultNamespace("http://c");  
    writer.writeStartElement("http://c", "a");  

    writer.writeCharacters(s);  
    writer.writeEndElement();  
    writer.flush();  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

User `XMLOutputFactory.createXMLEventWriter(stream, "UTF-8")` when you are creating the writer. I believe this should solve your problem.

I have not used this specific API but I used a lot others. For example escaping is done automatically by `Properties.store()` method if encoding does not support the characters.

Comment: sorry, the comment above is not right! I am first to use statckoverflow.com. I will add the java source.

Comment: Your example exactly confirms what I have said. All unicode characters are printed well if you are using UTF-8 and encoded when you are using other charset. So, what's wrong?

Comment: Using "UTF-8" is fine~~. But in generally, when XML is encoded in "GBK", why Chinese charachter is escaped? If customer insist using "GBK", is it can be fix technically?